# Asp.Net Core error while adding a nuget package

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package

I am migrating one API project from ASP.Net to ASP.Net Core. While trying to add a nuget package I am getting the below error:

> unable to find metadata of system.memory.4.5.1

**The .Net version I am using is: 2.1.0**

Comment: which nuget package you added?

Comment: Thanks for teh reply. But it got resolved once i closed all the instances of visual studio and when i re opened it and tried I was able to install the package.

Comment: @Khai Nguyen: I was trying to add a common package which is used within our organisation.

Comment: I can see few weird errors while trying to install packages. One of them was the above onethe other one is as below:

Comment: Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'http://dcsartifacts.dell.com/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-local/FindPackagesById()?id='runtime.rhel.7-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually build a package with the switch **-Verbosity detailed** to get more information and make sure you use the correct MSBuild for x64 or x86.